# QT scaling in ubuntu gnome creates big fonts

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, vlc-media-player, scaling, qt

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with gnome, and I'm having scaling problems with some QT applications (VLC, TexStudio). I use a HiDPi external screen and when I disconnect my laptop from the external screen, the icons and fonts become big and pixalated (images below). There is no problem when I'm connected to the external screen, the issue is on the laptop when I unplug it.

[VLC big and pixalated fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRwG5.png)

[TexStudio big and pixalated fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKpYX.png)

I have tried to set QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR, and QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS variables but nothing works for now.

If any one had the same issue or is familiar with the problem, I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh boot with the notebook docked in, the scaling is working fine on both screens (notebook screen and external one). After I dock out, the scaling seems to get messed up and feels like a factor 2.

I tried tweaking `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR, QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS and QT_SCALE_FACTOR`. Nothing worked.  Actually none of my screens is a hidpi one, but the notebook one has a bit higher pixel density.

If one is facing the exact same problem and is able to use one setting for all screens, then this works:

```
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
export QT_FONT_DPI=120
```

The DPI value can be set to any desired value of course.